RWR if one of PCC is not apostilled
I am an Indian citizen living in the UK who has a job offer from Vienna, belonging to the shortage occupation.
I came in contact with ABA (Austrian Business agency) who helps with the visa application. They suggested I should have two Police certificates, one from UK and one from India. Both of which should be apostilled. As is required by the Austrian visa immmigration.
UK PCC got apostilled but Indian PCC did not. The resson I was told is that the Indian PCC was already issued with a round seal by a competent indian embassy office, so it doesn't need any further legalisation in form of an apostille. The email I have from the embassy is that the authorities are welcome to email the embassy to inquire about the legitimacy of the certificate.
So I am not sure, if this would be okay for a visa officer in Austria, or they might trouble me for getting it apostilled. (Which I can't). What are my chances of getting the said RWR visa in this case?
Also, does anyone has an estimate of how long does RWR approval takes. I 've been told that the month of july-august are marred by summer holidays. so can take longer sometimes shorter.
